# Do monosyllabic past participles used as adjectives follow the comparative and superlative rules about adding -er/-est suffixes?

Tags: adjectives, past-participles, exam-questions, superlatives, comparative

This question showed up in my Writing part of F.C.E. test when I wrote

> TV is the **most bought** electric household appliance

In that moment, I wondered whether **boughtest** is the correct form instead of **most bought**.

Comment: Monosyllabicity is not a relevant factor.  The least|most *adulterated* dietary supplements...

Comment: I would use "TV is the *most often bought/purchased* electric household appliance." I would use *purchased* for expensive items, and *bought* for things like groceries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"-Er" and "-est" suffixes are used only for adjectives, not for past or present participle forms of a verb even though they can function as an adjective. For example:

> This is a sought after item. ( O )
>
> This is a more sought after item than X. ( O ) This is a sougter after
>   item than X. ( X )
>
> This is the most sought after item. ( O ) This is the soughtest after
>   item. ( X )

Another example:

Boring (or Bored) is derived from the verb to bore.

> It is more boring than X. ( O ) It is boringer than X. ( X ).

If you contrast it with the adjective "strong", the difference becomes clearer.

> It is stronger than X. ( O ) It is more strong than X (possible but
>   not idiomatic)